# fetch json data into swift uitable view

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

```
Below is my json file
```

and the url is http://localhost/country.php
   I want this data into uitable view swift 
     { name: ["India","USA","China"] }

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/country.php")
let userdata = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
do {
    let values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userdata as! Data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    print(values)
    print("Parse success")
} catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error)
    return
}
```

this is the code
please help

Comment: And what did you try so far? There are a lot of posts on SO on how to parse a simple JSON in swift. Btw. did you have a look at your url?

Comment: getting an error "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 2.}"

Comment: please show us some code how you tried to parse the JSON and where the error occurs (edit your question)

Comment: see the edited question

Comment: **Do not** use `NS*` types in `Swift` code without dire necessity.

Comment: What's wrong? In Swift3+, avoid NSStuff when Stuff is available: `NSURL` => `URL` for instance. Don't use `allowFragments`, that's not useful in your case. Also, avoid `NSData(contentsOf:)`, that's synchrone, meaning that block the current thread, and if it's the main thread, that blocks all your UI. Prefer `URLSession`. In Swift 4, give a try to Codable instead of manual `JSONSerialization`. Finally, avoid force unwrap (using `!`), prefers `if let`, `guard let`, etc.

Comment: @Larme I don't get it too. Since he is writing my answer doesn't meet his requirements but i am answering the above question (at least i think i do)

Answer (score 4):

So. First of all: Your `JSON` is not a valid `JSON` and your URL is (of course) not working. My guess is your JSON looks like that:

```
{
"name": ["India",
         "USA",
         "China"
        ]
}
```

If so you can change your code like that and it is working as expected:

```
let jsonString = """
{
"name": ["India",
         "USA",
         "China"
        ]
}
"""

let userData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userData) as! [String: Any]
    print(values)
    print("Parse success")
} catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error)
}
```

Like one comment already mentioned: Try to avoid `NS`types in Swift if it is not really needed.

Hope it helps.

And in addition: It is generally a bad practice to load a response from server sync. You should use `URLSession` and do it async. But this is another thing...

So the full example for your use case would look like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/country.php")!
let userData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

do {
    let values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userData) as! [String: Any]
    print(values)
    print("Parse success")
} catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error)
}
```

I force unwrap in the example above. I do not recommend that. Savely unwrap your optionals is the better way.

Comment: ... and it's also bad practice to specify `.allowFragments` if the expected object is a collection type. Omit the `options` parameter.

Comment: @vadian Thank you for the hint this is correct. I edited my answer.

Comment: I want to parse it from url

Comment: @JanviRamani Edited my answer. Like mentioned I couldn't use the url since it is adressed to localhost...

Comment: @JanviRamani If it is working and you like my answer i would appreciate it if you accept it :)